# Selenium Python: How to find web element in HTML by data-index attribute?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I'm trying to scrape a dynamic table using Selenium and I'm having a lot of trouble getting all the rows from the `tbody`. Within the HTML there are only 9 rows visible at a time, and those rows change but retain the same xpath when I scroll through the table. For example, when `data-index` is 50, `tr` in xpath is still between 1 and 9 depending on what position the row is on in the screen.

[image: screenshot]

The only item that doesn't change is the data-index attribute (as seen in the screenshot).

What I would like to do is something like this (high-level pseudocode)

```
for dataindex in range(min data index ,max data index):
    try:
          element = driver.find_element(By.(???(, "")
    except NoSuchElementException:
          scroll down table
          element = driver.find_element(By.(???(, "")
```

Comment: to scrap all the rows, you should first scroll down to the bottom of the page loading all the dynamic `tr`, and then simply locate/find them all at once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use CSS Selector to search for elements having specific attributes and values.

For example- for this case, you can use a CSS selector as `tr[data-index="<index>"]` ( replace `<index>` with a valid value)

so your reference code should be updated to this:

```
for dataindex in range(<min_data_index>, <max_data_index>):
    try:
          element = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, f'tr[data-index="{dataindex}"]') # used single quotes here to escape double quotes in selector
    except NoSuchElementException:
          #scroll down table
          element = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, f'tr[data-index="{dataindex}"]')
```

Also, if you're scrolling, you can use WebDriverWait to wait for the elements until they load.